# Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'react-native-vector-icon'

Tags: reactjs, react-native-web

I am using react-native-web and webpack in my project, I need to show  icons in my web app, I am trying to use [react-native-web-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web-vector-icons).

But I am getting the following error:

> ./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/lib/react-native.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native'

Need help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Need to alias react-native to react-native-web in webpack config.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    ...
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    },
  },
};
```